# Polynomial with modular coefficients library in python

Tags: python, polynomial-math, modular

does someone knows a simple library to do
calculations on Polynomial with modular coefficients?

I've seen numpy, but this one seems like it does not support
modular coefficients...

Thanks, 
Shai.

Comment: What do you mean by modular coefficients?

Comment: I mean coefficients over Z_p for some prime p:   for example 3 (mod 5) = 2 (mod 5)

Comment: What kind of operations do you intend to do? If it's just evaluation, then you don't need a special library. I guess if you're doing operations on the coeffs themselves, then you need some more sophistication!

Comment: Add, mult, fiv, mod, gcd, lcm, roots, stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to lift coefficients to integers.  For example if you want to compute
`(1+2x+3x^2)(3+2x+x^2)` in `Z/5[x]`, simply you compute `(1+2x+3x^2)(3+2x+x^2)` in `Z[x]`
and reduce it to `Z/5[x]`.

Thus

```
>>> import numpy.polynomial.polynomial
>>> c1 = (1,2,3)
>>> c2 = (3,2,1)
>>> numpy.fmod(numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polymul(c1,c2),5)
>>> numpy.fmod(numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polymul(c1,c2),5)
```

gives

```
array([ 3.,  3.,  4.,  3.,  3.])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sympy: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/index.html, in particular https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/domainsref.html#gf-p

```
from sympy import Poly, Symbol
x = Symbol('x')
p2 = Poly(x**2 + 1, modulus=2)
```